# Usage of make.unique for sample IDs

Tags: r, dataframe, sample

I'm trying to come up with a quick way of assigning some treatment IDs and...honestly I could do this faster on paper now but I have crossed the line to where I can't stop until I figure this out.

I want to make a table with 35 rows - each row would contain a vector with 9 numbers (between 1 and 12) but EACH ROW MUST BE UNIQUE.

I tried the quick solution that popped into my head:

```
data.frame(replicate(9,sample(1:12,35, rep = TRUE)))
```

but this obviously doesn't work for me because of "rep=TRUE" and "rep=FALSE" can't work as written because of the sample pool (1:12). Is there a way of adding make.unique to get at this?

Thanks!

Comment: Ironically, the challenge here is that there are so many possible unique values that the simple approach generating all unique values and picking 35 of them isn't practical.

Comment: @Gregor - yep, that approach takes somewhere on the magnitude of `19 Gb` worth of RAM...

Comment: Another option, a fancy option that I don't feel like coding up, would be to draw 35 numbers between 0 and 12^9 -1, convert them to base 11, break apart each number into columns of each "digit" (with leading 0s) and add 1 to each of the results.

Comment: @Gregor - that is clever...`int2B()` from library `cwhmisc` should make most of that pretty easy, along with `strsplit()`, `gsub()`, and some `as.integer()` for conversion.

Comment: @Chase yup. If this needed to be an efficient and implementation, that would be a good way to do it. My hunch is your answer is appropriate for OP's use case.

Answer (score 2):

There are probably more clever ways to go about this, but one relatively fail safe approach is to generate *way more rows* than you need and then simply take the top X `unique()` rows. Building off your code:

```r
set.seed(1)
x <- data.frame(replicate(9,sample(1:12,1e6, rep = TRUE)))
#how many rows did we make?
nrow(x)
#> [1] 1000000
#how many unique rows?
nrow(unique(x))
#> [1] 999906
#show the top two rows while showing how to get 35 rows total
head(unique(x)[1:35, ],2)
#>   X1 X2 X3 X4 X5 X6 X7 X8 X9
#> 1  9  6  8  3 12  7 11  5  5
#> 2  4  1  8 11 12 11 11  7  6
```

<sup>Created on 2019-10-07 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you want a unique combination, you can use `combn` to generate all possible combos and then take a `sample` of 35 random rows:

```
# all combos
x <- as.data.frame(t(combn(1:12, 9)))
# 35 random rows
x[sample(1:choose(12,9), 35), ]
```

Comment: I don't think `combn()` does what we want here. For example `combn(1:3,2)` generates the pairs `(1,2)`, `(1,3)`, and `(2,3)` when in reality what he's after is more along the lines of `expand.grid(1:3, 1:3)`. For the full problem, we'd need to generate `expand.grid(1:12, 1:12,1:12,1:12,1:12,1:12,1:12,1:12,1:12)` which would take `19.2` gig of RAM on my machine. While not intractable, that's a healthy amount of RAM unless you have some decent horsepower at your disposal.

Comment: OP just said they wanted "unique" rows, and a unique combination is the strictest possible interpretation of that. In any event, the 220 rows here would be a subset of the 12^12 rows from the `expand.grid` solution so still should work as an answer

Comment: OK sure that's fair. This solution works well until you need 221 rows instead of 35.